# Removing Children of DIV after certain Number

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this HTML

```
<div class="control">
     <label class="">Label Here</label>
     <input type="text">
     <div class="ui-resizable"></div>
     <div class="ui-resizable-handle"></div>
     <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
     <div style="display: inline;" class="delete"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span> </div>
     <div style="display: inline;" class="properties txtbox"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench">Properties</span></div>
</div>
```

How can i remove the second third and fourth Divs from this HTML using jQuery....

Comment: If i dont know how many divs will occur after the input field is there any way to CUT or SLICE all the divs or any elements that occur after the second child of the Control DIV...

Comment: Yes, you use the `:gt` selector. See the update in my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.control').find("div").slice(1, 4).remove();
```

Comment: hi, can you please guide me on how to remove a div with a particular index ? like for eg. I have 5 divs with the same class as "basicelements" ... i am able to find the index on Click event. Now how to I remove div.basicelements with index 1 or 2 or 3 which ever I have clicked? nothing has worked for me so far :(

Answer (score 16):

You're looking for `:nth-child`: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

It works like this:

```
$('.control div:nth-child(2), .control div:nth-child(3), .control div:nth-child(4)').remove();
```

Note that `:nth-child` uses *one-based* indexing, so the first element has index 1.

UPDATE: In response to this question the OP posted in a comment

> If i dont know how many divs will occur after the input field is there
>   any way to CUT or SLICE all the divs or any elements that occur after
>   the second child of the Control DIV...

The answer is yes, for this you want the `:gt:` selector: http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

```
$('.control div:gt(1)').remove()
```

As opposed to `:nth-child`, `:gt` uses *zero-based* indexing, so the first element has index 0.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.controll>div:gt(1)').remove();
```

`:gt` selector will let you select which has index greater then 1 theese are 3. elements and more

here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/Am7Vw/1/

Comment: this worked perfectly another sample code $('.pos_abs .mjx-box > span:gt(150)').remove();

Answer (score 0):

If you mean those specific ones:

```
$(".ui-resizable-handle, .delete").remove();
```

If you mean the divs at positions 2-4 no matter the markup, one of the `nth-child()` answers would work.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
$('.control div:nth-child(2)').remove();
$('.control div:nth-child(3)').remove();
$('.control div:nth-child(4)').remove();
```

Or you can do this as well

```
$('.control div:nth-child(1)').siblings().remove();
```

Comment: Your first solution won't work. After the first remove, there is one less element, so the indexes all change.